# Re-index with Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

Hi I have a student dataset consisting of their Names, Subjects and Scores.

Each student has 5 subjects to write. However the below table has data missing for some students in terms of their subjects and marks. Please find the table below:

```
Name    Subject Score
Harry   Math    4
Harry   Science 5
Harry   Social  3
Harry   French  5
Harry   Spanish 4
Steve   Math    5
Steve   Science 3
Steve   Social  5
Steve   French  4
Tom     Math    5
Tom     Science 4
Tom     Social  5
```

I would like to find Names which have scores for less than 5 subjects and append additional rows, so that all students have their individual scores for all 5 subjects. Expected output is below:

```
Name    Subject     Score
Harry   Math         4
Harry   Science      5
Harry   Social       3
Harry   French       5
Harry   Spanish      4
Steve   Math         5
Steve   Science      3
Steve   Social       5
Steve   French       4
Steve   Spanish      4
```

You can see here that Steve, Harry and Tom have scores for all 5 subjects.

Comment: How do you derive scores for the added rows?

Comment: I have raw data with which I will fill the data

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a perfect application of `reindex`

Given setup:

```
z=io.StringIO("""Name    Subject Score
Harry   Math    4
Harry   Science 5
Harry   Social  3
Harry   French  5
Harry   Spanish 4
Steve   Math    5
Steve   Science 3
Steve   Social  5
Steve   French  4
Tom     Math    5
Tom     Science 4
Tom     Social  5""")

df=pd.read_table(z,delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Name'].unique(), df['Subject'].unique()], names=['Name', 'Subject'])
df.set_index(['Name', 'Subject']).reindex(new_index)

                        Score
Name    Subject 
Harry   Math            4.0
        Science         5.0
        Social          3.0
        French          5.0
        Spanish         4.0
Steve   Math            5.0
        Science         3.0
        Social          5.0
        French          4.0
        Spanish         NaN
Tom     Math            5.0
        Science         4.0
        Social          5.0
        French          NaN
        Spanish         NaN
```